# Url for swagger in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

urls.py

```
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title="XYZ")

urlpatterns = [
    path('api_doc/', schema_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # regex for swagger creation
    path('?tag={id}&order_by={name}', views.QuestionList.as_view()), #url in swagger
    path('', views.QuestionList.as_view())
```

I am trying it in swagger and i am getting 404 response, what will be right url to get the response ?

[image]

Comment: query parameters are not part of the `path`. Those parameters are available in `request.GET` as a dict-like object.

Comment: so how to add them in swagger url ?

Comment: What's your Django version?

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api_doc/', schema_view, name='some_name'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # regex for swagger creation
    path('', schema_view), #url in swagger
    path('question_list/', views.QuestionList.as_view(), name='question_list')
```

Use non overlapping pattern in urls, give trailing slash and give a name attribute, so that you can call the url some other place

Comment: I didn't get your answer.

Comment: if you change the url as per the updated answer, you will get the swagger ui on home page

Comment: i am geeting swagger ui but how will i get 2 parameter during request like above picture

Comment: you have code the viewset and register the router, see the example app url https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/blob/master/example_app/tutorial/urls.py